# How to install a specific version of nginx on Debian 7?

Tags: nginx, debian, version, package

I did the following to nstall nginx on Debian 7

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo service nginx start
```

This installed the latest version of nginx , How do I install another version?
Doing     `sudo apt-get install nginx=1.2` or     `sudo apt-get install nginx-1.2` does not work. It fails saying `version not found?`

Comment: Use the google. This is not programming related and doesn't show much research effort besides wild guesses.

Comment: The commands that I tried out to use a specific version, are a result of using google. Had I known the answer I wouldnt have posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older version of Nginx is not available in Debian repository, you need configure Nginx Debian repository http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html or find the deb package and install manually.

Answer (score 0):

A distribution of Debian is a set of software packages that was tested to run well together. Every change imposes a risk to break somethign somewhere since that change may not have been prepared for by another software also installed.

When you are for a newever version than what the distributions ships, then a look at the package "tracker" will present an overview of what is currently available, which includes so-called backports to your distribution: https://packages.qa.debian.org/n/nginx.html but indeed the packages directly provided by nginx.org should be just fine. For looks into the past, check out http://snapshot.debian.org/package/nginx/ .